# Disable landscape orientation in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an app with reactJS. I am using webpack,sass and ajax for running the app and fetching data. I am in search of a function/logic where i can disable the landscape view. I want my app to be available only in portrait view and even if the user rotates it's phone, in the landscape view the app should not get resized.
I am finding solutions where there are options to customise this using tools. I need a solution where i can add this option similar to adding javascript code.

Comment: did you tried to set the view port width without any scale ?

Comment: @JEY yes i have tried that